# If $F : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{D}$ is an equivalence, does $\alpha_{GD} = G(\beta_D)$ hold in general?

Tags: logic, category-theory

Let $F : \mathbf{C} \rightleftarrows \mathbf{D} : G$ be an equivalence with natural isos $\alpha : 1_\mathbf{C} \to GF$ and $\beta : 1_\mathbf{D} \to FG$ witnessing the referred equivalence. I wonder if it holds generally that $\alpha_{GD} = G(\beta_D)$?

I think the answer is negative:

The reason is that, if it does hold necessarily, it seems that $\alpha$ is generally the unit of the adjunction
$F \dashv G$, since for any $f : C \to GD$ we have a unique $g : FC \to D$ given by $$g := \beta_{D}^{-1} \circ F(f) $$ such that
$$f = ((\alpha_{GD})^{-1} \circ GF(f)) \circ \alpha_C = ((G\beta_{D})^{-1} \circ GF(f)) \circ \alpha_C = G(\beta_{D}^{-1} \circ F(f)) \circ \alpha_C$$

And since I heard that it is not generally the case that if we have an equivalence between categories the natural isos witnessing it are the unit and counit, then it must follow that
$\alpha_{GD} = G(\beta_D)$ is not necessarily true.

Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your argument try to prove that the claim is false proving that every equivalence satisfying the relation $\alpha_{G}=G(\beta)$ should give an adjoint equivalence $\langle F,G,\alpha,\beta\rangle$, where $\alpha$ should be the unit and $\beta^{-1}$ the counit of the adjunction.

Your proof shows that if the relation given, namely $\alpha_{G(D)}=G(\beta_D)$, holds for every $D \in \mathbf D$ then $\alpha$ is the unit of **an adjunction** between $F$ and $G$.  Unfortunately your proof doesn't show that $\beta^{-1}$ is the counit of the adjunction and so it doesn't prove that the equivalence provided is an adjoint equivalence.

Indeed is true (take a look at the remarks after proposition 3.4.3 of Borceux's Handbook of categorical algebra-Basic category theory) that if $\langle F,G,\alpha,\beta\rangle$ is an equivalence $\alpha$ is the unit of *an adjunction* between $F$ and $G$.

So if I've understood correctly your argument it seems that it doesn't disprove (or prove) that in an equivalence it should be $\alpha_{G(D)}=G(\beta_D)$.

<strike>Nevertheless I think too that the claim is false, although I've no counterexample at hand.....at least for the moment. Need some time to come up with something</strike>

**Edit:** here's a counterexample (based on an exercise of Borceux's book).

Consider the category $\mathbf C$ with only one object and two morphisms:
$1_C$ and $f$, both having as source and target the only object $C \in \mathbf C$, where $f^2=1_C$.

In this category the morphisms $1_C$ and $f$ induce two natural auto-equivalences on the functor $1_{\mathbf C}$, hence the quadruple $\langle 1_{\mathbf C}, 1_{\mathbf C}, (1_C), (f)\rangle$ is an equivalence of categories, nonetheless $1_{\mathbf C}(f) \ne 1_C$ (in this context $G=1_{\mathbf C}$, $\alpha_{G(D)}=1_C$ and $\beta_D=f$).

Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, it is true that if $\langle F,G,\alpha,\beta \rangle$ is an adjoint equivalence then $\alpha_{G(D)}=G(\beta_D)$ for every $D \in \mathbf D$, that's a consequence of the [triangle identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities).

Comment: Hi Giorgio, thanks for the answer and reference! By the way, in Borceux's book, p.116, he suggests that we can let the unit of the desired adjunction be one of our canonical natural isos, say, $\eta := \alpha : GF \to 1_{\mathbf{C}}$. Then we show that it satisfies the UMP the unit since for each $b: B \to FA$, we have $(b \circ \eta_B^{-1}) \circ \eta_B = b$ and $b \circ \eta_B^{-1} =  Fa$ for some unique $a : FC \to D$.

Comment: But why can't we just replicate the argument to obtain both unit and counit in this way? i.e. additionally, let $\epsilon := \beta : FG \to 1_{\mathbf{D}}$ too. Why is that it doesn't work in general?

Comment: @StudentType think of the natural isos as *proofs* of the equivalences between the functors. 
An equivalence of categories provides two functors between the categories with two *proofs* that these functor are equivalences of categories.
In an adjoint equivalence we need to require something more, for instance we want that the two *proofs* satisfy the triangle identities.

Comment: I think that the point is that while we can choose many different, unrelated, *proofs* of the fact that $F$ and $G$ are equivalences, if we want that our proofs also .... prove that the functors are adjoint we need to choose them more carefully.

Comment: Finally if you look carefully to the counterexample above that exactly what it does: it takes two unrelated natural transformation between the identity functors, i.e. two elements of the set $\mathbb C^{\mathbb C}[1_{\mathbb C},1_{\mathbb C}]$. To prove that the functor $1_{\mathbb C}$ is self-equivalent we just need to provide an element of that set, this **could be** the identity but it **doesn't have to be** it.